# How can a .Net/C# Windows Forms application subscribe to events generated in a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, inter-process-communicat

I am considering creating a Windows service that collects data over TCP/IP, in this case a hundred or so bytes of Modbus data from PLC type hardware. I currently do this inside the application on a thread and would like to separate it. The thread runs with an elevated priority and polls the hardware on a timed interval. It works well.

This is used in near real-time environments and it would be nice if multiple applications can run without having to duplicate the polling. Making the thread a Windows service seems like a possibility.

My idea is to have the application subscribe to the registers (array items) that it is interested in. When the data changes in a subscribed register the service will send a notification to the subscriber along with the current value.

I need the event communication to be as fast as possible so I’m not sure what tool to use with the service. I don’t want to do any polling at the application level.

Comment: Why not just have a WCF interface between them and send updates directly?

Comment: @JeremyK Ignorance on my part. I thought that WCF was for web services and required going through a network stack.

Comment: Nope I use it for talking between apps all the time. Sounds like it should be a potential solution for you to go with. I like it because its quick to setup and does pretty much everything for you. Good luck

Comment: You don't want events anyway, they are too dangerous in an application like this.  Very important to focus on providing a consistent view of the I/O state with all signals updated atomically.  Easiest to do with a memory-mapped file and a named mutex that arbitrates access.  And make sure you don't jeopardize the scan rate when that mutex is held for a while.

Comment: @HansPassant The I/O states are updated atomically in the thread by using two banks. The current bank is switched after the update is complete. Then after the switch the comparator notifies the subscribers of the changes. By using events the main application just waits to be told to do something. In previous incarnations the application polled the I/O data continuously and was very inefficient, 100% CPU rate.

Comment: @JeremyK - This is not an area I have a great deal of knowledge. It looks like WCF has a a lot of capabilities, but I don't know what type of communication you are referring to that would ensure low latency transfers. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DrKoch - Can you be more specific about SignalR. The descriptions I see refer to web services.

Comment: I use SignalR for getting messages from a service to my WPF application.